# Animating HTML Text Change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to change the text of a HTML element using javascript and jquery. This is my code so far, and I can't seem to get it to work. I have googled it and can't seem to find anything on it.

```
$("div#title").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            $("div#title").html("Hello")
        }, "fast");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop.animate({
            $("div#title").html("Good Bye")
        }, "fast");
    }
);
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: What do you want to animate here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you are doing currently the syntax is incorrect, also you cannot animate a text as such instead you would need to animate an element holding the text. Also not clear on what peoprty you want to animate, Here couple of examples:

Animating Opacity:

```
$("div#title").hover(

function () {
    $(this).stop().css('opacity', '0').html(function (_, oldText) { // Set the opacity of the div to 0 and then change the html (flip it based on last value)
        return oldText == 'Good Bye' ? 'Hello' : 'Good Bye'
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1 // Animate opacity to 1 with a duration of 2 sec
    }, 2000);
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZkHF/)

Animating Width:

```
$("div#title").hover(

function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'width': '0px'  // Animate the width to 0px from current width
    }, 2000, function () {  // On completion change the text
        $(this).html(function (_, oldText) {
            return oldText == 'Good Bye' ? 'Hello' : 'Good Bye'
        }).animate({          // and animate back to 300px width.
            'width': '300px'
        }, 2000);
    })
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJAhL/)

Answer (score 7):

```
$("div#title").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).stop().html("Hello").hide(0).fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop().html("Good Bye").hide(0).fadeIn("fast");
    }
);
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FVcSk/)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this also

```
$("div#title").hover(
   function() {
       $(this).stop().fadeOut("slow",function(){ 
                $(this).html("Hello")
            }).fadeIn("slow");
},
   function(){
       $(this).stop().fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $(this).html("Good Bye")
            }).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The text can not really encouraged, you can change the content using html method.
Lettering.js is a plugin to play in a more visual with text.
http://letteringjs.com/

```
$("#title").hover(function(){
    $(this).html("Hello");
},function(){
    $(this).html("Good Bye");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Typing Style

```
<font size="7" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:150px; z-index:50;">Hello World!</font>
    <div id="test" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; height:100px; width:150px; z-index:60; background-color: #ffffff;"></div>
```

$('#test').animate({"left" : "150"}, 2000);

Answer (score 2):

I've coded one plugin for that purpose, you can check it on github: [*jquery-bubble-text*](https://github.com/WashingtonGuedes/jquery-bubble-text).

You can use it this way:

```
bubbleText({
    element: $element,      // must be one DOM leaf node
    newText: 'new Text',    // must be one string
});
```

Look one example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncs3uagj/).

Hope you enjoy it :)