# Effect for text change of a button

Tags: jquery, text, show-hide

i have a show/hide button, when it is clicked, it shows a content text, when it is clicked again, it hides the text. But i am NOT talking about this text but about the texte of the button.

The button shows alternately "Show" and "Close" at the clicks. My problem is that at the click, at the changing of the button text, the change is sudden. I would like to animate it, give an effect, for example the easeInCirc effect, so the "Show" and "Close" texts appear and disappear slowly, smoothly, gradually...

I found an answer of a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204009/animating-html-text-change-jquery) and tried to give an effect with opacity but my code below does not work, the button text does not show up with opacity...

HTML

```
<div class="bttn">Show</div>
<div class="content">here is the content text</div>
```

SCRIPT :

```
$(".bttn").click(function(){
    $(".content").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 700, 'easeInCirc');       
    $(this).css('opacity', '0').html(function (_, oldText) {return oldText == 'Show' ? 'Close' : 'Show'}).animate({opacity: 1}, 700);
});
```

I give you a nother code which i used before, if you know a solution with this one :

```
    // first i used this code
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "Show" ? "Close" : "Show");
```

Comment: to just animate the text, you have to wrap the text in some element such as a `span`, then animate the `span`, otherwise (animate the `div`) the whole button will be faded in/out, which does not look fine, try this http://jsfiddle.net/gyQ2W/3/

Comment: @King King : your answer is my answer, thanks a lot !!! I voted for this comment, you can not do it as an answer ? i would vote for it as an accepted one !

Comment: you're welcome, anyway it solved your problem :), sometimes I'm a bit lazy to add an answer, you know espeically when the asker wants something different,... a lot of edits will be made, ...

Comment: @King King anyway, i am satisfied 100%, let's back to work... :)